# Displaying .txt file in laravel View

Tags: php, laravel

I'm having a problem with trying to display data saved as .txt file in laravel blade view. the Laravel site was made by my predecessor and I'm assigned to add some features.

what I have tried :

- using iframe with src to file path. the file path is ~/tmp/somefile.txt (centos 7). result shows that my path is wrong.
  perhaps I need to do some routing to file? I tried routing it but I
  think missed something. it keeps going to /tmp/somefile.txt
- using php to dump the txt file. still, I think wrong file path
- using copy method to psql so I can call it from the database. but the text file is auto generated and has 600 lines so thats a big no

is there any workaround or solution to this? how do you link the laravel route to a local file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just read that file into variable and show it in your blade.

```
$txtFile = file_get_contents("test.txt");
```

or,

```
$myfile = fopen("webdictionary.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
echo fread($myfile,filesize("webdictionary.txt"));
fclose($myfile);
```

Comment: thank you. but my problem here is trying to get the path to work. replacing the test.txt  with /tmp/somefile.txt  I've also tried putting {{ Storage:url('<path>') }} but still doesnt work

Comment: In order to make Storage::url('<path>') work, you should place this .txt file inside `storage/app` folder

Answer (score 1):

you can use [get()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem#retrieving-files) function, or [asset()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem#configuration) if your file is in storage/app/public then only

```
Storage::url(<path>);
```

works better,

if your file is in public directory simply use

```
{{ asset(path)}}
```

it will work